# SMTPError: Password command Failed PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

The Requirement is that when the form is submitted the mail has to be sent the specified email address. For this I am using PHPMailer.
When I ran the code first time from localhost, I received **Critical Security Alert** received in Gmail, which I resolved by turning on "Allow Less Secure Apps" and also 
checked and approved the security event.
Now the code works perfectly in localhost powered by xampp but not in shared hosting. When I hit the submit button in the Form page present in shared hosting, I get the following message:

```
2020-02-25 09:48:40 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP t131sm5033428oih.35 - gsmtp<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:40 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO www.domain_name.com<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:40 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [AAA.BB.CCC.DD]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:40 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: STARTTLS<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:40 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:44 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO www.domain_name.com<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:44 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [AAA.BB.CCC.DD]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:44 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: AUTH LOGIN<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:44 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:44 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: [credentials hidden]<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:44 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:44 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: [credentials hidden]<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:45 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 &lt;https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&amp;scc=1&amp;plt=AKgnsbv534-5.7.14 ymrjiXdYur3ddtR_6o2GrGNO2DfOQ7VhdphcGz7dq3__0gTNj1-oIXqZ__3KYGCWXt-ZC534-5.7.14 znNW-khosAGrPwCN1mDscVVYa5ms25Ann9jrAUU39WELRqwVrSmhOMGa91Ec4JRu&gt;534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14  Learn more at534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t131sm5033428oih.35 - gsmtp<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:45 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 &lt;https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&amp;scc=1&amp;plt=AKgnsbv534-5.7.14 ymrjiXdYur3ddtR_6o2GrGNO2DfOQ7VhdphcGz7dq3__0gTNj1-oIXqZ__3KYGCWXt-ZC534-5.7.14 znNW-khosAGrPwCN1mDscVVYa5ms25Ann9jrAUU39WELRqwVrSmhOMGa91Ec4JRu&gt;534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14  Learn more at534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t131sm5033428oih.35 - gsmtp<br>
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:45 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2020-02-25 09:48:45 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection t131sm5033428oih.35 - gsmtp<br>
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.<br>
```

The PHPMailer code for sending mail follows:

```php
try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
            $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP

            $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                           // Set the SMTP server to send through
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->isHTML();
            $mail->Username   = 'username@gmail.com';   // SMTP username
            $mail->Password   = 'password';                     // SMTP password

            $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
            $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('username@gmail.com');
            $mail->addAddress('username@yahoo.com');    // Add a recipient

            // Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                        // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Mail subject';
            $mail->Body = 'Mail Body';

            $mail->send();
            echo 'done';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Mailer";
        }
```

The following actions have been taken:

1. Username and Password combination is correct and is not expired.
   Verified manually by logging via web and also sending mails from the
   localhost.
2. $mail->SMTPAuth=false cannot be set because majority
   of shared hosting providers seems to have disabled this for security
   reasons (mainly to avoid spamming and sending of unsolicited emails)

Comment: If "Allow less secure apps" is On, it might be possible you have 2-Step Verification enabled in your Gmail account. If this is the case, you need to create an App-specific password. https://www.lifewire.com/get-a-password-to-access-gmail-by-pop-imap-2-1171882

Comment: @ShashankShah Thanks for responding :) In this scenario, Two Factor authentication is not setup. In short, authentication is based on Username and Password. If it was there, I would have not been able to send mails even from localhost, which is possible. I can send mails from localhost

Comment: Seems like You just need to enable less secure apps for the Gmail account mentioned in $mail->setFrom( username@gmail.com )  to solve this.

Comment: @ShashankShah brother, Actually I have already mentioned that in my post.

Comment: Yeah, All possible cases I am reviewing is this only!  Let me dig into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a long battle I somehow managed to solve this. I activated DisplayUnlockCaptcha from the following URL:
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Probably because Gmail might have viewed the logins received from PHP file lying in hosting server as untrusted requests. This is because the hosting servers may reside in different places or countries and the login authentication request received would appear different other than the one  from where the Gmail account is logged in frequently. So as a security measure, it would have use some captcha mechanism in the background (which which cannot be viewed)

Answer (score 3):

Just for others info! To resolve this issue you have to go to:

https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps
then click Allow less secure app to YES

[image]

what does it mean to be less secure app? could we change our FAQ instructions and/or implementation so that users do not need to do this extra step?

if not possible, we should at least document in FAQ that user also need to change the setting on their google security account

**Your solution :**

Your server not supporting phpmailer.

Your account taken as a spam read here : [Prevent mail to Gmail users from being blocked or sent to spam](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)

**Use or fix App password**

If you've turned on 2-Step Verification and are trying to sign in to your Google Account through a device, mobile app, or desktop app, you'll need to enter an App Password.

See more and follow steps here : [Use or fix App password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2461835?hl=en)

If you're using SMTP (i.e. you're calling `isSMTP()`), you can get a detailed transcript of the SMTP conversation using the `SMTPDebug` property. The settings are as follows:

[Enabling debug output and troubleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#enabling-debug-output)

If you are having problems connecting or sending emails through your SMTP server, the SMTP class can provide more information about the processing/errors taking place.

Use the debug functionality of the class to see what's going on in your connections. To do that, set the debug level in your script.

Allow error levels For example:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4; //from 1 to 4 to get more details.
```

I had error almost same and this code was solved my problem because of my self signed certificate.

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

Once again see [SMTP Debugging](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging)

[Debug levels](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging#debug-levels)

[Debug output format](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging#debug-output-format)

Looks like you are trying to connect by curl api or something `SERVER: EHLO` if so! please add your codes to question.

Comment: While this does "fix" some issues, the "right" way as far as google is concerned is not to use the less secure apps switch, but to use XOAUTH2 for authentication instead, and that is covered in PHPMailer docs and examples. It's fiddly to set up, but it does work.

Comment: Yep I agree with you for big sites! Google says it’s not a good way to use less secure accounts, I do for years and didn’t have any problem except limitation 50 emails a day :) best way of sending mail is find a good hosting or vps server or build your own server, and setup as you like, for a small site I wouldn’t worry about less secure google account, none can hack it if you use secure password and securing your codes. Actually I don’t care what google says, they all wants us to use their products and earn money (all about money). So, read them but do what you want, not what they want :)

Comment: @Dlk Thanks for responding. I've already taken the steps that you have mentioned in your solution, which I've stated in my question too except XOAuth since that is not needed in my scenario. My server supports PHPMailer and the SMTP error log is also posted. Is there anything else I've been missing?

Comment: `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` I have set. So should my array key be `tls`?